# Why i see `u` in front of all the text in python text

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrap the website. My items are appearing like this

`{'company': [u'Resource Agility'],`

i am sick of this `u`.

is that normal?

i want to know that if i store my value in database, does the `u` also get in there?

Is there any way to hide that `u`?

Comment: psst! `u'this string is in unicode' r'this is a raw string, which means backslashes (\) don't escape anything, except the quote (\')'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No... the u is just [syntactic sugar for unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) in python 2.x. It won't be stored in your database.

Comment: It may matter to the database that your text is Unicode though. You may want to [`encode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) the text before saving it (though your database may do this for you).

Comment: thanks buddy , that `u` was driving me insane. i tried all sort of REGEX to replace it :)

Comment: glad to be of assistance, @user32

Answer (score 2):

The `u` symbol is  added in displaying the strings to represent that the object is a Unicode string. Similarly, if you use a unicode string in your code, you can use a unicode literal by adding a `u` symbol next to the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is how unicode strings are printed in console. Just read about them.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

It says "The small 'u' in front of the quote indicates that a Unicode string is supposed to be created."